# confusion about ddr3 addressing via MIG in kc705

Tags: memory, fpga, ram, memory-address, xilinx

I have been stuck with this problem for a month now and I am not able to understand it.
I have xilinx kc705 that have a 1GB memory organized as organized as (128 MB x 8) that is one [R]ank of 8, 8-bit devices. so the memory interface is 64 bits. Each device or chip is (128 MB) and has 8 banks (16 MB) each has 14 [R]ows and 10 [C]olumns. as the picture below: so there is 8 of this chip.

[memory organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C9VS.png)

The memory burst is 8.
when I use vivado to generate MIG,  it produces a user interface with a 28-bit address width and a 512-bit data width.

in MIG documentation address width is:  Rank+Bank+Row+Column = 1+3+14+10 = 28 bits. (B=3 as there is 8 banks in each device).

My questions are:
1- as the memory burst is 8, when I provide one address with one command (write or read) on the user interface side, the MIG will issue 8 commands towards the ddr3, that is why the data width is 512-bit (64*8=512) **IS THIS UNDERSTANDING CORRECT?**

**2- In the 28-bit address, does each address correspond to 1-Byte, 8-Byte(64-bit), or 64-byte(512-bit) and how do I increase it to reach the next location?**

My understanding is that each address correspond to 1-byte even though the ddr3 data width is 64-bit and that is because there are 8 chips and all get the same address but each get 8-bit part of the 64-bit. and when each of the chip perform the 8 burst, a 512-bit transfer is done. so I am confused about how to increase the address.

**should it be increased by 8 as it is correspond to 1-byte and 8 bytes has been written to each chip?**

or

**should it be increased by 64 as a total of 64 bytes has been written to the ddr3?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The burst length 8 is a property of the [DDR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#Overview) protocol. The way it works is that you request a single address, and get 8 words of data back. So you're correct that one burst will give you 64*8=512 bits, but the MIG core will only send one command to the DDR chips (aside from stuff like opening/closing the row).

From the way you describe the situation, I'm guessing that you're using the native MIG UI and not AXI. In that case, the addresses you send via the MIG UI are the actual address bits that go to the DDR chips. Since you have 128M words, you should have 27 address bits. But as you mentioned, MIG is giving you 28 bits. The extra one is the rank bit. This is unnecessary because you only have one rank, so that bit should always be 0. (That's just one of MIG's bugs/annoyances.)

With DDR3 and burst length 8, you always need to request blocks that are 8-word aligned. The [lower three column address bits have an effect on the order that the 8 words come back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_dynamic_random-access_memory#Burst_ordering), which is useful if you want one of the words back before the others. However, since MIG ultimately gives you all of the words at the same time, I'm not sure what will happen if you set those to anything but 0.

With the rank and lower 3 column bits always zero, that leaves you 24 bits of usable address space. Those 24 bits give you access to the full space of 512-bit blocks inside your 1Gbyte RAM. So yes, you should increment by 8.